# How to optimize the SQL query for finding coincidence among guests in a hotel database?

Tags: sql, mariadb

Coincidence. Have two guests with the same surname ever stayed in the hotel on the evening? Show the last name and both first names. Do not include duplicates.

Find the schema here: http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/Guest_House

Reference to the problem: http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/Guest_House_Assessment_Hard

```
select distinct book1.last_name,
case
  when book1.first_name < book2.first_name then
  book1.first_name
  else book2.first_name
  end as first_name_1,
case
  when book1.first_name < book2.first_name then
  book2.first_name
  else book1.first_name
  end as first_name_2
 from
(
  select booking_id, booking_date, guest_id, first_name, 
  last_name, nights
  from booking as bb inner join guest as gg
  on bb.guest_id = gg.id
) as book1 inner join (
  select booking_id, booking_date, guest_id, first_name, 
  last_name, nights
  from booking as bb inner join guest as gg
  on bb.guest_id = gg.id
) as book2
on book1.last_name = book2.last_name and
book1.booking_id <> book2.booking_id and
book1.guest_id <> book2.guest_id
where (book1.booking_date <= book2.booking_date
and ADDDATE(book1.booking_date, book1.nights)
> book2.booking_date )
order by book1.last_name
```

Is this the simplest way to solve this SQL problem of finding coincidence between two guests?

Note that this is *MariaDB* and that a user does not have access to any kind of write statements. So intermediate tables created with `INTO` cannot be used

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not the simplest.  You are looking for overlapping stays with guests having the same last name.

Start with the overlapping stays:

```
from booking stay1 join booking stay2 on stay1.booking_date <= stay2.booking_date
and dateadd(day, nights, stay1.booking_date) <= dateadd(day, nights, stay2.booking_date)
and stay1.booking_date < dateadd(day, nights, stay2.booking_date)
```

or something like that.

now get the guests:

```
join guest g1 on stay1.guest_id = g1.id
join guest g2 on stay2.guest_id = g2.id
```

and the final filter

```
where g1.last_name = g2.last_name
```

and just to make sure it's not the same person

```
and g1.id <> g2.id
```

I'll leave the select clause in your capable hands.

Comment: note that the requirements are to match last names where guest_id is not the same. It is not to match last_name with first_name

Comment: oops.  minor detail.

Comment: Checking for overlapping range:  `WHERE a.start <= b.end AND a.end => b.start`  (assuming `start` and `end` are `DATEs`)